# Word document message

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, apache-poi, openxml

I'm creating a Word document and it works but it shows a message before opening.

[image]

I'm using a one page template that I open and append many times to the first one. With only one page I didn't have any problem, so I guess the appending is where the problem is. I copied the method and I understand what it does but I can't see any problem.

```
private void appendBody(CTBody src, CTBody append) throws Exception {
    XmlOptions optionsOuter = new XmlOptions();
    optionsOuter.setSaveOuter();
    String appendString = append.xmlText(optionsOuter);
    String srcString = src.xmlText();
    String prefix = srcString.substring(0,srcString.indexOf(">")+1);
    String mainPart = srcString.substring(srcString.indexOf(">")+1,srcString.lastIndexOf("<"));
    String suffix = srcString.substring(srcString.lastIndexOf("<"));
    String addPart = appendString.substring(appendString.indexOf(">") + 1, appendString.lastIndexOf("<"));
    CTBody makeBody = CTBody.Factory.parse(prefix + mainPart + addPart + suffix);
    src.set(makeBody);
}
```

The code that uses the method is:

```
@Override
public XWPFDocument createCertificates(CandidateList candidateList, String signName, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    List<CandidateList> candidates = candidateListRep.findCandidateList(candidateList.getCategory(), candidateList.getCode(), candidateList.getCourseDate().toUpperCase());
    CourseName description = courseNameRep.findDescription(candidateList.getCode(), candidateList.getCategory(), candidateList.getAdminYear());


    XWPFDocument firstDoc = createDocument(candidates.get(0), description.getDescription(), signName);
    candidates.remove(0);
    CTBody firstCTBody = firstDoc.getDocument().getBody();

    for (CandidateList candidate : candidates) {

        XWPFDocument doc = createDocument(candidate, description.getDescription(), signName);
        CTBody docCTBody = doc.getDocument().getBody();

        appendBody(firstCTBody, docCTBody);
    }

    return firstDoc;
}

 private XWPFDocument createDocument(CandidateList candidate, String courseDesc, String singName) throws IOException {

    File wordDoc = new ClassPathResource("/static/templates/Certificate.docx").getFile();
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(wordDoc.getAbsolutePath())) {

        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);


        List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = doc.getParagraphs();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph;
        List<XWPFRun> runs;

        replaceText(paragraphs, 12, "Name", candidate.getName() + " " + candidate.getSurname());
        replaceText(paragraphs, 29, "CourseName", courseDesc);
        replaceText(paragraphs, 42, "Sign", singName);

        return doc;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `appendBody` method you are showing is simply bad practice. A word document is **not** a concatenation of multiple `CTBody` elements. It should contain only **one** main `CTBody` element. If a page break is needed, then there should be a `XWPFRun` having a [BreakType.PAGE](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/BreakType.html#PAGE) added.

Comment: Could you please print and check if `prefix+mainPart+addPart+sufix` contains valid xml/data?

Comment: @AxelRichter that's what I first tried but then I couldn't copy the list of paragraphs into the new page. I had a couple of methods to do this that worked well but I couldn't iterate through them. I'm going to try again. Thanks!

Comment: If Word shows that message, the Open XML markup you create is not valid. To understand what exactly is wrong, you should include the Open XML markup in your question.

Comment: @ThomasBarnekow I'm not using the appendBody method anymore because, as mention by Axel, is a bad practice. I'm using a template and now is working well. Thanks!